# How to have 2 connections with 2 different set of models with Mongoose?

Tags: mongoose

I could not find anyway to define 2 set of models and use them in the connection I want..

How may I do?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create two connections and add different models to each one:

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var db1 = mongoose.createConnection('localhost', 'test');
var Cat = db1.model('Cat', new mongoose.Schema({ name: String }));

var db2 = mongoose.createConnection('localhost', 'test');
var Dog = db2.model('Dog', new mongoose.Schema({ name: String }));
```

In this example, the 'Cat' model is tied to connection `db1` and the `Dog` model is tied to `db2`.

Comment: perfect! because from what I've seen looks like: mongoose.model('Cat', Schema)... so it's on the singleton, that's why I couldn't figure out.. maybe there is a doc about this, but they seem to matter to simplicity.. even if in large apps it's not usefull (I think)