# Mongoose and Typescript - Link a model to a specific mongoose connection

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, typescript

I defined a Model in a ts file.
I would like to use a specific mongoose connection (not the default one) with that model.
How can I associate my model to the connection ?

Excerpt form my TS file :

```
export interface iSuppliers extends mongoose.Document {
suppliers: string[];
fields: number[];  
}

export const supplierSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    suppliers: {type:[String], required: true},
    fields: [Number]})
.index({suppliers: 1}); // Additional index

export const supplier = mongoose.model<iSuppliers>('supplier', supplierSchema);
```

In my server.ts file :

```
import {supplier} from '....';
....
let database_2 = mongoose.createConnection(....);
```

Nothing happens when I use my supplier model to find data.
Obviously, I need to bind it to my database_2 connection ...

I am not sure about the way to that....

Comment: could you elaborate just a wee bit?

Comment: I edited my comment with more details...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to have 2 connections with 2 different set of models with Mongoose?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12937883/how-to-have-2-connections-with-2-different-set-of-models-with-mongoose)

Comment: Not a duplicate. That answer is pure javascript...

Answer (score 1):

I found out my way...

I export a function that returns the model and use my connection as a parameter...

```
export function importedGameDatabase(mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection) { return mongooseConnection.model<iImportedGames>('importedGame', importedGamesSchema); }
```